# Getting null back from YQL Yahoo

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, yql

I am using the YQL of Yahoo to get some data. I need to send my request Yahoo's YQL because If is normally uses an AJAX request I will get CORS error's. I had worked for several months now but today. I am only getting this back:

```
query: {count: 0, created: "2017-09-09T08:06:15Z", lang: "nl-NL", results: null}
```

I don't know what I can do I have tried keep sending requests until you got a result but it's just keeps loading.

The AJAX request:

```
var REST_PUBLIC_BITTREX = "http://www.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/";
var REST_CURRENCY_BITTREX = REST_PUBLIC_BITTREX + 'getcurrencies';
var getAllAvailableCoinsBITTREX = function () {
    var url = REST_CURRENCY_BITTREX;
    var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
    $.ajax({
        'url': yql_url,
        'data': {
            'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="' + url + '"',
            'format': 'json',
            'jsonCompat': 'new'
        },
        'dataType': 'jsonp',
        'success': (function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('Bittrex',data);
            if (data.query.results == undefined) {
                getAllAvailableCoinsBITTREX();
            }
            else{
                getThePriceOfAvailableCoinsBITTREX(data.query.results.json);
            }
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: What are you sending down in your request? What do you expect to get back?

Comment: I am sending a request to the API from Bittrex and I except to get data of cryptocoins back

Comment: Please share how you're sending down the request.

Comment: I have edited and add the code

Comment: Because the code in the question uses `'dataType': 'jsonp'`,  that code and any possible problem you’re running into with it have nothing to do with CORS. So by (re)tagging it with the `cors` tag (and removing the `jsonp` tag), you’re just wasting the time and attention of people here who are expecting the `cors` tag to only have questions that are actually related to CORS. So please consider (re)removing the `cors` tag and (re)adding the `jsonp` tag so that it’s more clear to other people here what the question actually relates to.

Comment: Okey I understand it but when I send the request trough a normal AJAX request is got CORS problems .That is the reason why I tagged it with CORS and not JSONP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was trying to get to find an other proxy and it give me an error unsecure. Because of the proxy wasn't https.

So I checked my Bittrex link again: 
I was http. 
So I say lets try it with https. 
And the Yahoo YQL started to return values back.

The only thing I needed to do was this:

Change that: `"http://www.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/";`

In to this: `"https://www.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/";`